# Two Way Binding not working

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-binding, mvvm, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-8

I am new to two way binding in wp7.The below code does not assign the textbox value to the object automatically and returns null.

**Xaml:**

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" DataContext="{Binding usd}" Grid.Row="1" Margin="14,10,10,-10" > 
        <TextBox Text="{Binding UserName,Mode=TwoWay}" Name="txt1" Width="200" Height="60" FontSize="20" Margin="128,48,128,499"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Password,Mode=TwoWay}" Name="txt2" Width="200" Height="60" FontSize="20" Margin="128,263,128,284"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Email,Mode=TwoWay}" Name="txt3" Width="200" Height="60" FontSize="20" Margin="128,159,128,388"/>
        <Button Content="Send" FontSize="18" Margin="179,413,170,129" 
        Click="Button_Click_1" />
  </Grid>
```

**Cs:**

```
public class UserLogin:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _username;
        private string _pwd;
        private string _email;

        public string UserName
        {
            get
            {
                return _username;
            }
            set
            {
                _username = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("UserName");
            }
        }
        public string Password
        {
            get
            {
                return _pwd;
            }
            set
            {
                _pwd = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Password");
            }
        }
        public string Email
        {
            get
            {
                return _email;
            }
            set
            {
                _email = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Email");
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
```

**Instantiation:**

```
public UserLogin usd = null;
```

**In constructor:**

```
usd = new UserLogin();
```

**In Button ClickEvent:**

```
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

//            ContentPanel.DataContext = usd;

            MessageBox.Show(usd.Email);
        }
```

Null reference exception in Message box statement. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just bind to public properties - so your: DataContext="{Binding usd}" should be wrong because usd is just a field

btw if you set this in your ctor too, an remove the xaml binding it could work

```
usd = new UserLogin();
ContentPanel.DataContext = usd;
```

Comment: gr8.. your suggestion works gr8. but then why cant we set the databinding in the xaml?

Comment: because your usd is not set as a property its just a variable....
do one thing

public UserLogin usd {get;set;}

usd = null;

Answer (score 0):

About your control/page (which XAML belongs to it)

1. it's datacontext should contain a **usd** property
2. that property should also **notifying property**!
3. of course your control/page's datacontext class also should implement **INotifyPropertyChanged**

Answer (score 0):

because your usd is not set as a property its just a variable.... do one thing

```
public UserLogin usd {get;set;} 
usd = null;
```